# How to sort elements based on integer value in elements?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting, integer

I need to sort array elements based on the integer value that it contains.

Current output is :

```
array[0] -> Indica 4 PAX

array[1] -> Indigo/swif Dezire/Etios  11 PAX

array[2] -> Tavera 8-10 PAX

array[3] -> Innova 10 PAX

array[4] -> Tempo Traveller 7-9 PAX
```

But actually I need like:

```
array[0] -> Indica 4 PAX

array[1] -> Tempo Traveller 7-9 PAX

array[2] -> Tavera 8-10 PAX

array[3] -> Innova 10 PAX

array[4] -> Indigo/swif Dezire/Etios  11 PAX
```

Comment: i need to print this array based on ascending order sorting of integer value in the array

Comment: Raghu, usually you show some code that you have tried already alongside your question and expected inputs and outputs.

Comment: Are these numbers always integers?

Comment: What if two different elements contain the same number value, which order should they come in?

Comment: Woah, question parameters have changed.  Now you want to sort by integer ranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has the `mysql` tag on it, so I'll assume your data is coming from resultset rows.  I also see that all of your number values are the 2nd last non-whitespace substring in your strings.

For this reason, your sorting process can be handled effectively in the mysql query using this `ORDER BY` clause:  ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9923ba/2/0))

```
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`yourfieldname`,' ',-2),' ',1) AS UNSIGNED),`yourfieldname`
```

The above clause says: isolate the 2nd last substring and cast it as an unsigned number.  This ensures that "natural sorting" is performed (so that `12` doesn't come before `3`).  As a secondary sort criteria, I am using the fullstring to break ties.

That said, if your actual strings don't always obey that structure, I'll next recommend `array_multisort()` because it performs fewer iterated regex function calls.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/TFMqP))

```
$order=preg_replace('~\D+~','',$array);  // generates: ['4','11','10','10','9']
array_multisort($order,$array);  // sort $array as $order is sorted
var_export($array);
```

You can even write it as a one-liner: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/pqQed))

```
array_multisort(preg_replace('~\D+~','',$array),$array);
var_export($array);
```

*A pattern adjustment for handling your hyphenated number substrings: `~-\d+|\D+~`
This will remove non-digit characters and digits that follow a hyphen.

All above methods will take this input:

```
$array=[
    'Indica 4 PAX',
    'Indigo/swif Dezire/Etios  11 PAX',
    'Tavera 10 PAX',
    'Innova 10 PAX',
    'Tempo Traveller 9 PAX'
];
```

and provide this output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Indica 4 PAX',
  1 => 'Tempo Traveller 9 PAX',
  2 => 'Innova 10 PAX',
  3 => 'Tavera 10 PAX',
  4 => 'Indigo/swif Dezire/Etios  11 PAX',
)
```

Comment: I like the SELECT ORDER  approach.  But it's my understanding that number ties will result in a slightly different order to your other solutions.  (Innova 10 PAX followed by Tavera 10 PAX, which personally is what I'd desire.).

Comment: I'd better re-check my methods.    `Innova` should come before `Tavera`.

Comment: OP's example doesn't warrant that, but it could be an oversight.

Comment: @Progrock Turns out the only method of mine that was getting the tiebreaker wrong was the `usort()` method with the spaceship operator.  (I just didn't post my answer accurately)  When it was a tie, there was "no movement", so it stayed out of order like in the input.  AlivetoDie's answer does not show this fault, but that is pure luck.  His method swaps by default on ties. If the input order was reversed, his answer would not obey alphabetic sorting.  I've removed my `usort()` call because it does two `preg_match()` calls on every iteration/comparison, so it is not going to be efficient.

Comment: (I dare say I enjoyed the preg_replace / array_multisort, though you do loose the keys.)

Comment: @mickmackusa i have used this array_multisort(preg_replace('~\D+~','',$array),$array);  
and its worked for me but i have other case see my question i have just edited and reply me

Comment: Your change is slightly ambigious.  Do you want to match the first number or the second number in each string.  For your sample, it doesn' matter but in your project, fringe cases may arise.  Please clarify your intent.

Comment: @RaghuVenkataa If you are querying the database, I really want to urge you to prepare your resultset in advance, by adding this ORDER BY clause: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9923ba/2/0  If my answer satisfies, please award the green tick.

Comment: @mickmackusa i have awarded the green tick

Answer (score 1):

If you have two integers that are the same, you ultimately then might want to then sub sort by name.

```
<?php
$data=[
    'Indica 4 PAX',
    'Indigo/swif Dezire/Etios  11 PAX',
    'Tavera 10 PAX',
    'Innova 10 PAX',
    'Tempo Traveller 9 PAX'
];

$int_filter = function($str) {
    return filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
};
$sorter = function($a, $b) use ($int_filter) {
    $cmp = $int_filter($a) <=> $int_filter($b);
    if($cmp === 0)
        $cmp = $a <=> $b;

    return $cmp;
};
uasort($data, $sorter);

var_export($data);
```

Output:

```
array (
    0 => 'Indica 4 PAX',
    4 => 'Tempo Traveller 9 PAX',
    3 => 'Innova 10 PAX',
    2 => 'Tavera 10 PAX',
    1 => 'Indigo/swif Dezire/Etios  11 PAX',
)
```

Comment: Why submit two separate answers?  You can merge them into one post.  As I have.

Comment: Different approaches.

Comment: I have provided 3 separate approaches.

Comment: Why are you preserving the indexes?  The OP doesn't want that.

Comment: The OP states that they want to print the array.  Likely the indexes won't matter, but if using the result say in a web form, they may want them.  If indexes are not wanted, use `usort` instead of `uasort`.  Or they can always call `array_values` on the result.

Comment: This answer will not work as desired because you are performing string sorting: https://3v4l.org/eHMgB  Please edit

Answer (score 0):

May be you will like using this.

I just referred one example from [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php).

```
<?php
$arr = [];
$arr[0] = 'Indica 4 PAX';

$arr[1] = 'Indigo/swif Dezire/Etios  11 PAX';

$arr[2] = 'Tavera 10 PAX';

$arr[3] = 'Innova 10 PAX';

$arr[4] = 'Tempo Traveller 9 PAX';
function cmp($a, $b) {
    $a = filter_var($a, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $b = filter_var($b, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
uasort($arr, 'cmp');
var_dump($arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$data =
[
    'Catnip 23 units',
    'Cheezy chips 18 units',
    'Refried beans 21 units' 
];

$int_filter = function($str) {
    return filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
};
$int_values = array_map($int_filter, $data);
asort($int_values); // Order int_values and maintain keys.

$ordered = array_replace($int_values, $data);
var_export($ordered);
```

Output:

```
array (
  1 => 'Cheezy chips 18 units',
  2 => 'Refried beans 21 units',
  0 => 'Catnip 23 units',
)
```